# Unthreading a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have to unthread a binary tree. what I mean by this is that I have the following method

```
  public static <T> BinaryNode<T> unthread(BinaryNode<T> root)
```

that receives a double threaded binary tree and it is supposed to return an unthread tree - which means, it has to delete the additional nodes that used to be null making them null again.

The way I think I should do this is to make a linked list with every node and then call a helper method that would have as parameters the threaded tree and the linked list. Then, traverse the tree and if a node had already been visited it means that I have to delete it.

I don't know if that is going to work. What are your suggestions?

Comment: What is a "double threaded tree"?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "doubly linked"? meaning that the child nodes have a reference up, and the parents also have references down.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to binary nodes like in a heap data structure and convert them to single-link nodes like the ones in a linked list.

Comment: well they taught it to me as a double threaded binary tree it means that its linked left and right

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree

Comment: The `threaded` word is confusing most people I think (at lest it confused me), since it refers to multi-threading. You may use branch instead, as this is IMHO more-appropriate for data structures

Comment: @IvayloSlavov but do you know what i mean by threaded right. its a tree where a left null child its linked  to its predecesor in the indorder traversal and every right null child is linked to its succesor in the inorder travelsal

Answer (score 0):

it worked :). i used a preorder traversal and a linkedlist. as i said if the node was in the linkedlist and didnt add it and thats it.